# Does the python.org installer of python come with pip, and how do I use it?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I can download python 2.7.12 from python.org, and all python versions from 2.7.9 onwards are supposed to come with pip, but after installing it, using pip in the terminal does not work.
I am on macOS.
Have I installed pip, and if I have, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have informations about pip:

https://packaging.python.org/installing/

normally python from python.org come with pip, maybe you should just update...
to update from terminal:

`pip install -U pip setuptools`

After when you need to install package, for example `numpy`, just do in a terminal:

`pip install numpy`

more informations here :

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

you can also use `conda install` from anaconda as an alternative of `pip` :

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/get-started.html

Comment: I cannot run the pip install etc because the pip command does not work.

Comment: is there an error message when you try `pip install -U pip setuptools` in the terminal ? if yes, can you post it ?

Comment: it just says: -bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Comment: I am setting up conda instead

Comment: there's a path problem, normally pip is not in `/usr/local/bin/` here you can try to download it and install it once again with get-pip : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I think I'll just stick with conda... seems quite easy to use. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Multiple instances of Python can coexist on your machine. Thus you could have installed Python 2.7.12 yet, when you call Python from terminal, you may be calling an older version.

To know which version you are using, type `which python` in terminal and look at its path. Then from Python in terminal, type

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

to get the exact version.
As [Dadep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6048114/dadep) says, I would recommend using `conda` to isolate your invironments if you have to play with multiple Python interpreters. Further conda simplifies 3rd party package installation process beyond doubt.