# No Module Named Extern

Tags: python, pip

I am having real trouble trying to use pip to install pyserial for python 3.5.2, I am trying to install pip using 'sudo easy_install pip'.

I keep getting this error message:

```
sudo easy_install pip
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==29.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2697, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2370, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2376, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12 intel/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named extern
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: here informations about using `pip` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873272/does-the-python-org-installer-of-python-come-with-pip-and-how-do-i-use-it/40874059#40874059

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo easy_install pip` will install pip for Python 2, which you don't want if you're using Python 3.

You might have pip installed for Python 3 already (run `which pip3` to check). If so, you can install pyserial using `pip3`

```
pip3 install pyserial
```

However, it would be better to use a virtual environment. See the [hitchhiker's guide to Python to get started](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).